# Storing PIDs From the Result of PS command into an array

Tags: bash, awk, ps

Hope you are having a good day.

The intention is to write the PIDs of some of the running processes into an array for further use.

```
Function()
{

    declare -a arr

    ps -e -o pid,%mem,command |

    awk -v val="$1" '{if($3 == val) print $1,$2,$3; $arr+=($1)}'
}
```

It seems I can't have access to arrays/variables inside awk.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: awk is a totally different tool+language to shell. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Answer (score 1):

The Bash array `arr` is not accessible inside of awk, or even outside of the function.  It looks like you're filtering specific *commands* in the `ps` output.  So let's simplify this as:

```
declare -a arr=( $(ps -e -o pid,%mem,command | grep "$1\$" | tee /tmp/pid$$ | cut -c-5) )
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
cat /tmp/pid$$
```

- This assigns values to the array in the declaration.
- The array values are taken from the *output* from the ps/grep/cut commands.
- The argument to grep looks for "any line that ends with `$1`".
- The `cut` is just taking the first argument, which is the PID of each process.
- The `tee` sends the intermediate output to a file for printing (optional).
- The `printf` meets your "further use" requirement.

Comment: Thanks, Such a great solution. I was just wondering if it could be achieved by awk? Because my actual condition is more complex and my bash knowledge is not enough to rewrite your expression. Mind if I edit the solution with the actual condition? also I guess it's good to mention that my future use is simply killing the processes upon the user request.

Comment: In that case... you must use array indexes.  Something like this AWK script:
`{ if ($3 == val) { print $1,$3; arr[i++]=$1 } }; END {for (v in arr) print "pid " arr[v]}`.